# c# regrex for a string repeated multiple times

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy

I would like to have a regualr expression for the string where output would be like:

```
CP_RENOUNCEABLE
CP_RIGHTS_OFFER_TYP
CP_SELLER_FEED_SOURCE
CP_SELLER_ID_BB_GLOBAL
CP_PX
CP_RATIO
CP_RECLASS_TYP
```

I tried using regex with
string pattern = @"ISNULL(*)";

```
string strSearch = @" 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(CP_RENOUNCEABLE,'x2x'))), ISNULL(CP_RIGHTS_OFFER_TYP,-1), LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(CP_SELLER_FEED_SOURCE,'x2x'))),
                 LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(CP_SELLER_ID_BB_GLOBAL,'x2x'))),ISNULL(CP_PX,-1), ISNULL(CP_RATIO,-1), ISNULL(CP_RECLASS_TYP,-1);

  string pattern = @"ISNULL(*\)";            

 foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(strSearch, pattern))
            {
                if (match.Success && match.Groups.Count > 0)
                {
                    var text = match.Groups[1].Value;

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that we'd be having a comma after our desired outputs listed in the question, which then this simple expression might suffice,

```
(CP_[A-Z_]+),
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/i2f7FX/1/)

If my guess wasn't right, and we would have other chars after that such as an space, we can add a char class on the right side of our capturing group, such as this:

```
(CP_[A-Z_]+)[,\s]
```

and we would add any char that might occur after our desired strings in `[,\s]`.

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/OgxRcY/1/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(CP_[A-Z_]+),";
        string input = @"LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(CP_RENOUNCEABLE,'x2x'))), ISNULL(CP_RIGHTS_OFFER_TYP,-1), LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(CP_SELLER_FEED_SOURCE,'x2x'))),
                 LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(CP_SELLER_ID_BB_GLOBAL,'x2x'))),ISNULL(CP_PX,-1), ISNULL(CP_RATIO,-1), ISNULL(CP_RECLASS_TYP,-1);";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Edit:

For capturing what is in between `ISNULL` and the first comma, this might work:

```
ISNULL\((.+?),
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/ZpbtV6/1/)

Comment: Hi Emma,
sorry about the confusion.  I want the string between substring between "ISNULL(" and next ",". So my regex should be somehting like ""ISNULL(*\)". Not very sure about what is the exact regex I should use? I hope that makes sense.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you! I really appreciate it.